# System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 Error

Tags: c#, wcf, portable-class-library

I'm using ObservableCollection in a portable library but I'm getting the error below. How can I solve this problem?

> 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1<MyClass>' does
>   not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

edited:
I have this class in a portable library

```
Class A
{

public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyList { get;set;}

}
```

and trying to use it in a WCF Service.

```
myA.MyList.Add(new MyClass());
```

Second Edit:
I figured it out by putting my class having the observable collection property to a different project/library. But I'm still wondering why I got that strange error.

Another solution for this question would be a better solution structure for my projects. I'm still trying to manage it.

I am designing a Silverlight project consuming a WCF service. I have some common classes to share in both Silverlight and the WCF Service. I could not make it work by using just a portable class and share because I need some data structures to use like ObservableCollection and SortedList etc. Portable classes do not have this. Because of that reason I am having Surrogate classes in different libraries but this doesnt look good.
How should I design it?

Comment: Can you provide more information? What platforms are you targeting? Can you repro this by creating a small repro project targeting the same platforms?

Comment: I'm targetting Silverlight 4.5 and higher

Comment: Without a repro, I'm not going to be able to help. Can you repro this in a small project targeting the same platforms? What's the list of *all* the platforms that you are targeting?

Answer (score 1):

The error sounds like you're trying to add an item of type `ObservableCollection` to an existing `ObservableCollection` that is made of a list of `MyClass` objects, like:

```
ObservableCollection<object> miscList = new ObservableCollection<object>();
ObservableCollection<MyClass> realList = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
realList.Add(miscList); // miscList isn't a "MyClass" object =[
```

Try checking the line that's throwing the error and making sure that you're passing in the right variable (might be a typo).

**UPDATE**
Your code example confirms that this is the case. You define your list as `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`, which means that any object that is inserted into this list *has* to either by an instance of `MyClass` or inherits *from* `MyClass`.

In the following line, you're attempting to add an object of type `A` to the list, and `A` is neither `MyClass` nor does it inherit from `MyClass`:

```
myA.MyList.Add(new A());
```

To fix this, you will either need the class `A` to inherit `MyClass` (`class A implements MyClass`), change your list to be `ObservableCollection<A>` instead, or rethink the reason why you need to add a type `A` to that list (maybe you'll need two lists instead?).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not trying to add a different type object but the class is defined in a portable library. Could this be the reason ? Should I fix somewhere to prevent this ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your most-recent code additions. Give it a read-over and let me know if this helps out or not =]

Comment: My mistake. It was a typo. I fixed the question again. In real life scenario, code is too much complex but to summarize it, I have a GameTable object having ObservableCollection of Player objects. In my WCF service, I'm trying to manipulate the list but I'm getting this strange error.

Comment: I guess this is either from referenced assemblies or because of portable library

Comment: @Kubi I don't have much experience with Silverlight (didn't realize your question was for that originally), but I've done some research regarding this issue and several sources say you need to add a reference to the `WindowsBase` dll in your project. Can you verify that you either have this already, or try to add it?